# Why does the Pythagorean theorem involve squares rather than any other powers?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Is there a common property of spaces, where one squares coordinates to obtain distance (such as Euclidean, Minkowski spaces), responsible for this choice of power (i.e. 2)?

Comment: It means there is a consistent inner product.

Comment: For instance, you can prove that of all the $\ell^p$ spaces, only $\ell^2$ is a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0):

The Pythagorean theorem says nothing about the second power. It is about areas of squares (geometric figures); see the Elements by Euclid, book I, proposition 47 (e.g. [here](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/propI47.html)).

The second power appears in a modern, simplified formulation, and it comes from the property of a square: the area of a square is a second power of its side's length. Which in turn is a result of the fact that a square is a 2-dimensional figure.

Comment: This is pedantic.  Of course the Pythagorean theorem uses the second power - after it has been suitably translated to modern mathematical language.  For that matter, you might as well argue that the Pythagorean theorem says nothing about "the area of squares" either, since it was all in Greek and Euclid would not understand that particular phrase.

Comment: There is an interesting distinction to be made between the way the Greeks thought about this theorem and the way we think about it.  But it is essentially the same theorem.